# Gradle executes all tasks?

Tags: gradle

I have a very simple build script like so

```
task hello{
    println("hello World")
}

task bye {
    println("bye")
}
```

On the command line I run
`gradle hello` and I get the following output:

```
hello World
bye
:hello UP-TO-DATE
```

Why is it executing the task "bye" (I'm assuming it gets executed since "bye" gets printed)? Thanks.

Comment: Thumbs up for the question. I was having the same issue today and wondering why it's happening!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737494/why-is-my-gradle-task-always-running

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's a common pitfall:

```
task hello {
    println("Any code in here is about *configuring* the\
    task. By default, all tasks always get configured.")
    doLast {
        println("Any code in here is about *executing* the task.\
        This code only gets run if and when Gradle decides to execute the task.")
    }
}
```

The distinction between configuration phase and execution phase is probably the single most important concept to understand in Gradle. It can be confusing at first, and may go away in the future. A kind of analogue in the Ant/Maven world is that these tools first parse XML build scripts and build an object model (perhaps resolving some properties along the way), and only then execute the build.

Comment: Thanks, that sure clarifies things!! :)

Comment: This problem is not there for if the task type is GradeBuild. It is not clear when to add the doLast option

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Peter answer, If you want to execute all task , you can specify the defaultTasks list.

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'run'

task clean {
    doLast {
        println 'Default Cleaning!'
    }
}

task run {
    doLast {
        println 'Default Running!'
    }
}

task other {
    doLast {
        println "I'm not a default task!"
    }
}
```

Output

```
Output of gradle -q
> gradle -q
Default Cleaning!
Default Running!
```

More details can be found here
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html