# gradle tasks -all throwing error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have test build.gradle file as follows

```
task someTask(type: Sync) {
   def folder = new File('fold1/fold2/');
   if(!folder.exists()) {
        throw new GradleException('Folder Absent');
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

When I do `gradle tasks --all` it is running the task and throwing exception. I was thinking that only when this task is run that it will check for folder but it is actually running it for any task I run.

Can someone suggest workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executed during the configuration phase and not during the execution phase. You need to put it in a `doFirst` or `doLast` block:

```
task someTask(type: Sync) {
    doLast {
        def folder = new File('fold1/fold2/');
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            throw new GradleException('Folder Absent');
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

See also: [Why is my Gradle task always running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20738571/4365460)